# Echo a value after a word in a file in Windows bash

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a config file that contains the following:

```
~some stuff~  
name test  
type online  
user me  
password hello  
serverip 192.168.20.1  
timetolive 500  
randomvar 200  
~some more stuff~
```

I wish to write a bash that finds and displays the current `serverip` in this file.

Desired output:

```
192.168.20.1
```

I'm using `findstr serverip` but its output is:

```
serverip 192.168.20.1
```

Any easy way to remove "ip" in the results?

Comment: Why are you using `findstr` (a Windows command) in a `bash` shell script?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. I remove the erroneous tags, this is meant for Windows command only.

Answer (score 0):

#### Any easy way to remove "ip" in the results?

Use the following batch file named `test.cmd` (where the config file is named `config.txt`)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type config.txt ^| findstr serverip') do (
  set _line=%%i
  set _output=!_line:serverip=server!
  echo !_output!
  )
endlocal
```

Example:

```
> type config.txt
~some stuff~
name test
type online
user me
password hello
serverip 192.168.20.1
timetolive 500
randomvar 200
~some more stuff~
> test
server 192.168.20.1
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- [Type - Display a text file - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html)
- [variable edit replace - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)